# force generic parameter two implement one of two interfaces c#

Tags: c#, generics

Is there anyway to force a constraints for a generic definition to implement one interface of two when I can not touch both interface

I want to do it for the IComparable interface:

```
class A<T> where T :IComparable IComparable<T>
```

I do not want the T must implements both interface but on of them

Is there any way to do it when I can not change the IComparable?

Comment: There is no "OR" clause in the constraint.  That wouldn't make any sense, you'd be back to having to write "does it implement it?" code.   The point of generics is to not have to write such code.

Comment: What is your use case for it?

Comment: I am writing a specific list that inheritance from list but actually behave different from list in many context
I keep this list sort all time and for this I use binary search.
binary search require one of the IComparable

Comment: Why directly use `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>` instead of `Comparer<T>.Default`?

Comment: `IComparer<T> comparer=Comparer<T>.Default; comparer.Compare(x,y);` Or you can accept `IComparer<T>` in your constructor, so user of your list can specify custom sort order.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one interface and wrap the other.

```
class A<T> where T : IComparable
{
}

class ComparableWrapper<T> : IComparable
      where T : IComparable<T>
{
    T _obj;
    public ComparableWrapper(T obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }

    public T WrappedObject {get { return _obj;}}

    // wrapping code
}
```

This way, you can use both IComparable and IComparable